# Vector display iterator ends prematurely

Tags: c++, file, vector, output

I'm currently working on a final project for one of my introductory classes in college, and I can't seem to find out why my output is cutting out prematurely. I'm trying to append the lines of a text file in the same directory into a vector and randomly select from the vector to get a name for an enemy in a text-based fighting game, but during testing it seems like the vector either only contains three items or the last for loop (the one before the comment blocks, I'm working on it in chunks) only displays three of the possible names. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    srand(time(0));
    
    int userInput;
    int player_health = 100;
    int boss_health = 200;
    int boss_index = rand() % 3;
    ifstream boss_list;
    string boss_name = "";
    string boss_inputs[3] = {"MACHINE GUN", "BOMB ATTACK", "CANE SMACK"};
    string user_inputs[3] = {"SWORD ATTACK", "BOMB ATTACK", "MAGIC ATTACK"};
    vector<string> boss_list_holder = {};
    
    
    unordered_map<string, int> attacks = {
        {"SWORD ATTACK", rand() % 100},
        {"BOMB ATTACK", rand() % 100},
        {"MAGIC ATTACK", rand() % 100}
    };
    
    
    unordered_map<string, int> boss_attacks = {
        {"MACHINE GUN", rand() % 75},
        {"BOMB ATTACK", rand() % 80},
        {"CANE SMACK", rand() % 50}
    };
    
    boss_list.open("names.txt", ios::in);
    
    while(getline(boss_list, boss_name)) {
        //cout << boss_name << endl;
        boss_list_holder.push_back(boss_name);
    }
    

    for(int j=0; j<(sizeof(boss_list_holder)/sizeof(boss_list_holder[0])); j++) {
        cout << boss_list_holder[j] << endl;
    }

    
    //cout << "BOSS FIGHT SIMULATOR\n\n";
    
    /*
    while(userInput > 3 || userInput < 1) {
        cout << "Enter the attack you want to use!\n";
        
        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(user_inputs)/sizeof(user_inputs[0]); i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << ". " << user_inputs[i] << " ";
        }
        
        cout << "\n";
        
        cin >> userInput;
        
    };
    */
    
    
    
    /*
    cout << boss_inputs[boss_index] << " ";
    cout << boss_attacks[boss_inputs[boss_index]];
    */
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(boss_list_holder)/sizeof(boss_list_holder[0])
```

This is a very old-fashioned way of deducing the length of an array, and indeed it only works for *arrays*.

It doesn't even work on pointers, which people often have instead of arrays without realising it, so `std::size(boss_list_holder)` is a better general solution.

In your case, simply `boss_list_holder.size()` is your best bet.

You should also be using `unsigned int` (or, ideally, `std::size_t`) for array or vector indices, and your compiler will warn you about unsafe signed/unsigned comparisons if you stick with `int`.

(Some people will go further and recommend `std::vector<string>::size_type`, though personally I think that's overkill.)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Having trouble remembering all the predefined methods, functions, etc.

Comment: @JustinMcCown You don't need to remember them! You only need to consult [a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Technically speaking, `std::vector::size_type` should be used instead, which is *commonly* `size_t`, but is not *required* to be, it could be something else.  Consider using `auto` instead, when feasible, eg: `auto size = boss_list_holder.size(); for(decltype(size) j = 0; j < size; ++j)` Though a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) would be better: `for(const auto &boss: boss_list_holder) { ... }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I addressed that ;) `std::size_t` is assuredly large enough, so...

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop over the `boss_list_holder` vector is wrong:

```cpp
for(int j=0; j<(sizeof(boss_list_holder)/sizeof(boss_list_holder[0])); j++)
```

This `sizeof` trick only works for fixed-sized arrays (like your `user_input`), where the elements are stored directly in the allocated memory of the array itself.

This does not work for dynamic containers like `std::vector`, which `boss_list_holder` is an instance of.  The elements of a `std::vector` are not stored in the allocated memory of the `std::vector` object itself (ie, `sizeof(boss_list_holder)` is not equal to `sizeof(string) * NumberOfStrings`).  They are stored in an array that is allocated elsewhere in memory, and the `std::vector` object simply holds a *pointer* to that array (amonst other things).

You need to use the vector's `size()` method instead, that will return the number of elements that have been put into the `std::vector`'s inner array:

```cpp
for(size_t j = 0; j < boss_list_holder.size(); ++j)
```